# Creating an R function with an argument that determines the language of a column(s) levels

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a function that changes a column's language based on one of the arguments.

Let's say you have a dataset with values for species, written in English. So, for example, there's a species column with "frog", "rabbit", and "cat". In French, it would be "grenouille" and "lapin" and "chat". However, there are also some typos in the English or levels you'd like to amend.

```
code     species   value
<fct>    <chr>     <dbl>
01        frogg     23
02        rabbit    45
03        cat       90
```

I want a function that lets someone specify that they want the species column to output the species name in French. I'd also like to fix typos in the English names at the same time as well. Assume the data gets updated each month. So, you'd provide the path to the new file in the first argument (the variables always stay the same) and then what language you want it to be as the second argument.

I'm thinking the function would have two arguments. The first is just for calling in the data. The second argument is to specify which language you'd like. So, the idea is that you'd do function(x, language = "FR"), and then the function would provide something like this:

So, for example, it would output lie this

```
function(file = x, language = FR)

code     species   value
<fct>    <chr>     <dbl>
01       grenouille 23
02        lapin     45
03        chat      90
```

or

```
function(x, language = EN)

code     species       value
<fct>    <chr>          <dbl>
01        frog            23
02        rabbit          45
03        cat             90
```

Doing this is more difficult than I expected. Initially, I thought I could just nest a series of `case_when()` arguments within an `ifelse()`, kinda like this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

my_func <- function(file, language) {
raw_data <- read_excel(file)
raw_data |>
mutate(
  species = ifelse(language = FR, case_when(code == "01" ~ "grenouille",
                                            code == "02" ~ "lapin",
                                            TRUE         ~ "chat),
                                  case_when(code == "01" ~ "frog",
                                            TRUE         ~ species))
}

my_func(file = x, language = FR)
```

However, this didn't work. Instead, I got an error that said there was an "unexpected |>" or it couldn't find the raw data object.

I tried various if statements (`if`, `ifelse`, `if_else`,`case_when`) and expected that it would assess the specified language (i.e., language = "FR") and assign the proper column levels. I thought a `switch` statement might also work, like the below

```
my_func <- function(file, language) {
raw_data <- read_excel(file)
raw_data |>
mutate(
  species = switch(language,
                   FR = case_when(code == "01" ~ "grenouille",
                                  code == "02" ~ "lapin",
                                  TRUE         ~ "chat),
                   EN = case_when(code == "01" ~ "frog",
                                  TRUE         ~ species)
}
```

This didn't work either, and I got the same error.

Is anyone able to advise on this? What are best practices when nesting conditionals within conditionals for something like this? Is the issue trying to pass a character vector as an argument in the function? Let me know if anything is unclear. Thank you!

Comment: The first example has mismatched quote marks.  The second one has mismatched parens.  Maybe the real code had problems like that too?

Comment: My advice is when you are tempted to write a lot of parameters into your code; dont; write the parameters into proper datastructures, data.frames typically, and then you can lookup parameters by simple joins etc. I think you need a dictionary table/frame that you can join on

Comment: Thanks, Nir. You're right, it's much easier to just create a reference table and use `left_join` to create the table in the other language. My thinking was, instead of having two functions, have one that allows the person using the function to specify the data and language they want. I figured I wasn't good enough at writing functions and someone else would know, but it seems complex functions that can do a bunch of different things isn't always ideal. My thanks to you again for making me realize that the kinds of functions I wanted to do isn't really better or ideal. Take care

Comment: "complex functions that can do a bunch of different things isn't always ideal": one function, one job.  Build more complex structures from simple building blocks.